# Were people in the USA surprised and shocked by the launch of Sputnik in 1957?

Tags: space

Were a lot of US citizens, especially US leaders, surprised and shocked when the USSR launched the first artifical satellite, Sputnik 1, in 1957?

Comment: Absolutely. It was so surprising that even a new [Contract bridge (card game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge) convention, the [Sputnik Double](https://www.bridgehands.com/N/Negative_Double.htm), later renamed the *Negative Double*, was named after it because both were "out of this World".

Comment: What specifically would you like to know that is not covered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_crisis)?

Answer (score 4):

It was quite a shock, and not only in the US, but in Europe too. There were thousands of pictures/talks/articles about it, as there were in july of 1969, for the next step of the "race to the stars".

> On October 4, 1957, the Soviet Union launched the earth’s first artificial satellite, Sputnik-1. **The successful launch came as a shock to experts and citizens in the United States**, who had hoped that the United States would accomplish this scientific advancement first. [Office of the Historian, Foreign Service Institute - US Dept. of State](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1953-1960/sputnik#:%7E:text=The%20successful%20launch%20came%20as,accomplish%20this%20scientific%20advancement%20first.&text=The%20fact%20that%20the%20Soviets,behind%20in%20developing%20new%20technology.)

> The launch — the anniversary of which coincides with the beginning of World Space Week — **came as a surprise to scientists and officials in the U.S.**, though **they quickly downplayed their shock**<sup>1</sup> that the USSR had the ability to get a heavy satellite into orbit, a feat the U.S. had not yet accomplished. [TIME - Oct. 3, 2017](https://time.com/4958422/sputnik-1957-report/)

The New-York Times writes about how "*there was no advance warning of Sputnik*" and that "***news of the world's first man-made satellite burst onto the front page and stayed there for weeks.***". Even "*Sputnik's radio signals, rebroadcast by television and radio stations around the world, immediately captured the public's imagination.*" [New-York Times - October 5, 1957: The Soviet Union's Big Surprise](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/partners/aol/special/sputnik/main.html)

> Though Sputnik was a relatively simple satellite compared with the more complex machines to follow, **its beeping signal from space galvanized the United States to enact reforms in science and engineering education so that the nation could regain technological ground it appeared to have lost to its Soviet rival**.
>
> Sputnik’s radio signal highlighted not only the fact that the Soviet Union had beaten the United States into space, it also made it clear the Soviets possessed rocket technology strong enough to launch nuclear bombs at the United States. [How Sputnik changed U.S. education - Harvard Gazette](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2007/10/how-sputnik-changed-u-s-education/)

There's even a thesis ([Space Race: African American Newspapers Respond to Sputnik and Apollo 11](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc5115/)) that "*examines how two scientific accomplishments achieved during this time affected ideas about education, science, and living conditions in the U.S.*"

---

<sup>1. you usually don't downplay someone's achievement unless it's a big hit/milestone and you've been outplayed. It was the cold war, and expected, but yet...</sup>